# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0

I have following code to get table data in a object but I am getting error and I don't know where I am wrong.

```
    public List<ModelGetEmployeeList> GetEmployeeList()
            {

               List<ModelGetEmployeeList> empList = new List<ModelGetEmployeeList>();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                string q = "select uid,fname,lname from nworksuser;";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(q,conn);
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd); ;
                conn.Open();
                adapter.Fill(dt);
                conn.Close();
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        //Here I am getting following error
                        // Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
                        empList[i].uid = row["uid"].ToString();
                        empList[i].fname = row["fname"].ToString();
                        empList[i].lname = row["lname"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                return empList;
            }
```

And ModelGetEmployeeList Class is like this-

```
public class ModelGetEmployeeList
    {       
        public string uid { get; set; }
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `empList` is empty.

The proper way to add a `ModelGetEmployeeList` to your list is by:

```
ModelGetEmployeeList employee;

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    employee = new ModelGetEmployeeList();
    employee.uid = row["uid"].ToString();
    employee.fname = row["fname"].ToString();
    employee.lname = row["lname"].ToString();

    empList.Add(employee);
}
```

Comment: No problem @DipakAkhade

Comment: And no need to open and close the connection as data adapter takes care of it